# Open a pdf file with adobe reader and fill in data from excel with vba

Tags: excel, vba, pdf

spent endless hours to find a solution on an issue, to fill in 1 data into left upper corner of a pdf file and sign it, which file opened with Acrobat Reader DC, based on its name which has a uniq ID in an excel file. This is anyway a scanned document, not a form. In the excel file next to this Uniq ID is the string of numbers I have to copy there.
I have found on web many different aspects of this issue, VBA codes with added API and JSON portions, but cannot understand, maybe my knowledge is very very low on this.
Many cases the first step I struggle to find and choose the right references in VBA. On my PC I can see only below, but none of them was suggested in codes Ive found.

Acrobat Access 3.0 type library
Acrobroker lib
Adobe Acrobat 7.0 browser control type library 1.0
Adobe reader file preview type library

I know I have to share some result but at this point no any result, no any code I was able to use...maybe you have a solution I can try to apply.
Many thx in advance

Comment: As mentioned I am doing tasks: 1 sign, 2 put a string of nrs into the corner and save it. If this is the case you mention in your answer and you have solution I am very curious.

Comment: I have an excel database, with hundreds of rows. Different products,  each with a uniq ID, and a uniq financial position nr. We have a server folder, uploaded by finance hundreds of 1 pager pdf files, which are scanned invoices. We are not allowed to add extra pages, nor modify these scanned files. We have to find and open invoices belongs to us, search by previously mentioned Uniq ID which is in the name of the file, and if we opened, we have to fufill above mentioned position nr with red in left corner and sign it, than save without change name of the file. Hope clear now

Comment: maybe my explanation is wrong so we are in wrong direction. Problem for me not that cannot fill in nrs onto pdf but want to save time. I want a loop whihc find the pdf, open it, fill in the string and save it into another folder. But seems if I have no PRO version I cannot do this. Above mentioned bates numbering is not working as want me to open as free trial or buy some higher level of Adobe. thx anyway

Comment: thank you very much for your time, dig deeper myself in this topic